# Symfony2 add class active in menu

Tags: php, class, symfony, twig

```
{% for node in menu.nodes %}
<li><a href="{{ page_url(node,node.defaultParams) }}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a simple way to add an class="active" for the current node ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to solve it with a macro. It works like this (untested code typed here directly):

```
{% macro menuitem(route, params, text) %}
{% set _url = path(route, params) %}
  <li{% if _url == app.request.requesturi %} class="current"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ _url }}">{{ text }}</a>
  </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

This method will add the current class if the route you're generating right now is the one the user requested.

For simpler usage import it: `{% from _self import menuitem %}`

Usage: `{{ menuitem("blogpost", { "id": 1 }, "my first blogpost") }}`

Also note that I'm using silex, where the current request is accessible via `app.request`, not sure about it in the full-stack framework.